# iOS: How to know if an email address is a gmail account

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmail, mobile-application

Example gmail account which can login on mail.google.com:

xxx@gmail.com,

xxx@mycompany.com > gmail account

I need to know if an email address is a gmail account.

note: I'm using objective-c for iOS app.

Comment: Hi @Hezron, you can compare the string for '@gmail.com' at the last. By this  probably you can know if the user mail is from gmail or not.

Comment: What is the context? Where do you get these emails from?
Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263888/how-to-detect-if-an-email-is-a-google-account